# Real algebraic solution

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose a system of polynomial equations with rational coefficients has a real solution. Does necessarily there exists a real solution with algebraic coordinates? What about the simplest case of one polynomial equation in two variables?

Comment: I think this is true, more or less by definition, if the solution set is discrete. If it is not, you can make it discrete by adding several linear equations.

Comment: @Alex Can you explain more on the discrete case?

Comment: I'm not an expert, that's why I'm just commenting, but basically, you can solve the system by computing consecutive resultants. The last one is univariate, and it's roots are algebraic by definition. Going back ("back substitution"), you get univariate polynomials with algebraic coefficients, hence algebraic roots. Experts must know a smarter way of explaining this.

Comment: I am not sure this is a research-level question.  First of all, since the "singular locus" of an irreducible algebraic variety over a (perfect) field (say $\mathbb{Q}$) is also an algebraic variety over that same field with smaller dimension, then by induction on the dimension you may assume that your real point is in the smooth locus.  Now consider a coordinate projection that is smooth at that real point and use the implicit function theorem / inverse function theorem.

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev:  I am sure that your hint can be made into a proof, but the general question of "descending rational points" is tricky.  Certainly you need to use some special property of the real numbers.  There do exist field extensions $L/K$ and $K$-varieties $X_K$ such that $X_K$ has an $L$-rational point, yet $X_K$ has no $F$-rational point for any finite subextension $F/K$ of $L/K$.

Comment: @JasonStarr Yes, of course, something is used here that I skipped as trivial. E.g., to make it discrete and still rational and nonempty, one should use the fact that rationals are dense :)

Comment: @Alex and Jason: one "special property of the reals" is this: since the field $K$ of real algebraic numbers is real closed, the embedding $K\subset \mathbb{R}$ is "elementary" in the language of ordered fields. This immediately implies the result.

Comment: @Mostafa: If you know that your variety is absolutely irreducible and has a real point in the smooth locus, then it even has a *totally real* algebraic point. This follows from the main result of my paper avaliable [here](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/ASENS/ASENS_1989_4_22_2/ASENS_1989_4_22_2_181_0/ASENS_1989_4_22_2_181_0.pdf).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The is an immediate application of the "real Nullstellensatz", in *exactly* the same way that one answers the analogous questions between $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}$ and $\mathbf{C}$ by using the usual Nullstellensatz (over $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}$!).  I trust that the OP knows this latter application of the usual Nullstellensatz. It is just a proof by contradiction.

Namely, suppose $F \hookrightarrow F'$ is an inclusion between real closed fields (such as $F' = \mathbf{R}$ and $F$ the subfield of algebraic numbers inside $\mathbf{R}$) and let $f_1, \dots, f_n$ be a finite collection of polynomials in variables $X_1, \dots, X_m$ over $F$.  Given that the $f_i$'s have a common zero in $F'$ we want to claim the same in $F$. Suppose to the contrary that the $f_i$'s have no common zero in $F$.  Then the "real Nullstellensatz" (for real closed fields) says that $-1 = \sum g_j f_j + \sum h_k^2$ for some $g_j, h_k \in F[X_1,\dots,X_m]$.  But this identity persists over $F'$, where it obstructs the existence of a common zero of the $f_j$'s over $F'$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 4):

The statement also follows from Tarski's theorem (1951) that the first-order theory of real closed fields is quantifier-eliminable. Namely, this theorem implies that if a first-order formula holds in some real closed field, then it holds in all real closed fields. One can apply this result to the field of real numbers and the field of real algebraic numbers (both of which are real closed fields). In particular, if a system of polynomial equations with rational coefficients has a real solution, then it also has a real algebraic solution.

In fact this proof gives a bit more: the real algebraic solutions are dense among the real solutions (the topology is the usual one coming from the Euclidean metric).

I know two more proofs, let me just give the key ideas. The first one is based on the fact (a consequence of the Tarski-Seidenberg principle) that the projection of a semialgebraic set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ (by forgetting the last coordinate) is semialgebraic. The second one is based on Theorem 3.1 in Chapter IX of Lang's algebra.